# Add SpecialRowPromptField to multiple columns on ultragrid

Tags: c#, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have a filter row at the top of a grid with two columns.  If I use this code to set the `specialrowpromptfield` it only sets it on the second column.  Is there a way to set this for multiple columns?

```
    e.Layout.Bands[0].SpecialRowPromptField = e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns[0].Key;
    e.Layout.Bands[0].SpecialRowPromptField = e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns[1].Key;
```

Thanks,

---

**Answer:**

Looks like this is not something that can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As from Help

> Specifies the key of the column whose cell to position the special row
>   prompts in.

You can specify just one column (by its Key). The only other option available (as far as I know) is to let the property to null. In this way the prompt spans  from the first column over the adjacent columns.

Of course, your code, set, as prompt field, the column at Index 1 because the last one used overwrite the previous setting.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping there was a way to add it to multiple columns.  I would think that if they are going to let you set this property to one of the columns in a filter row why not do it for all or some...

Comment: As I have said, I don't think it is possible. However, let's see if someone from Infragistics checks this question and gives you a better answer.

Comment: @DROPtableusers Steve is correct that this is only possible for a single column.  There are more details in the help: http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/Current/CLR4.0/?page=Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v13.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridBand~SpecialRowPromptField.html